# Как пройтись циклом в массиве по наклонной?

Tags: c#, массивы, математика, emgu

Имеется массив двумерный, внутри которого содержатся некие значения. Есть повернутый прямоугольник в этом массиве. Мне нужно пройтись по каждому элементу внутри этого прямоугольника. Имеются координаты углов прямоугольника и угол.
З.Ы RotatedRect emguCV.

Comment: А в каком порядке?

Comment: @VladD Без разницы, мне нужно просто получить значения из этого массива.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, например, так.

Предположим, что верхняя вершина имеет координаты `(x0, y0)`, вектора сторон `(dx1, dy1)` (влево-вниз) и `(dx2, dy2)` (вправо-вниз).

Тогда код, перечисляющий координаты значений внутри, такой:

```
double x0 = ..., y0 = ...;
double dx1 = ..., dy1 = ...;
double dx2 = ..., dy2 = ...;
// double важно из-за деления

var x1 = x0 + dx1 + dx2; // координаты противоположной точки
var y1 = y0 + dy1 + dy2;

var ymin = (int)Math.Floor(y0);
var ymax = (int)Math.Ceiling(y1);

for (int y = ymin; y <= ymax; y++)
{
    var minRowX1 = (y - y0) * dx1 / dy1 + x0;
    var maxRowX1 = (y - y0) * dx2 / dy2 + x0;
    var minRowX2 = (y - y1) * dx2 / dy2 + x1;
    var maxRowX2 = (y - y1) * dx1 / dy1 + x1;
    var minRowX = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Max(minRowX1, minRowX2));
    var maxRowX = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Min(maxRowX1, maxRowX2));
    for (int x = minRowX; x <= maxRowX; x++)
    {
        // (x, y) - точка внутри
    }
}
```

Для случая, когда прямоугольник может вылезать за края массива, нужно добавить ещё ограничения:

```
var ymin = (int)Math.Max(Math.Floor(y0), 0);
var ymax = (int)Math.Min(Math.Ceiling(y1), h - 1);
```

и

```
var minRowX = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Max(Math.Max(minRowX1, minRowX2), 0));
var maxRowX = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Min(Math.Min(maxRowX1, maxRowX2), w - 1));
```

соответственно.

Код не работает для случая вертикальных сторон (деление на ноль), этот случай тривиален и легко рассматривается вручную.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Надеюсь будет полезно и остальным, т.к в поиске не нашёл ничего.

Comment: @Horoko: Пожалуйста! Я подправил ответ, там была опечатка.

Comment: Извините, а вектора стороны, dx1 dy1 это координаты точки где заканчивается этот вектор? Соответственно координаты вершины, это начало этих векторов?

Comment: @Horoko: нет, это координаты самого вектора

Comment: @Horoko: Вот вам пример: http://pastebin.com/cXSUxTFa

Comment: @Horoko: Или вот: http://ideone.com/y20TPZ (`(dx1, dy1) = (-3, 3)`, `(dx2, dy2) = (3, 3)`)